# Completing from filesystem search in ido-find-file

Tags: ido, ido-find-file

By default, when a pattern that has been typed matches no results, after a short pause in typing `ido-find-file` goes on to try to locate a matching file in one of recently visited directories (I believe, in the recent-first order).

My question is, are there any ido features or extensions available to include a whole filesystem subtree, not only a list of visited directories, to the ido search? I understand this is tricky in general (what happens if I stop typing at `/`?), but I am all for spending some time configuring this extension to do what I want. I am working on a project with a zillion directories, shell scripts calling scripts calling scripts. Even setting explicit fixed expansion points would be fine by me, for example, a rule to the effect *if you are at or below any directory in this configured list, expand all subdirectories of that directory for ido search*).

I know about `helm`, but I am interested how far I can go with `ido`, before jumping into the learning of such a complex package.

Comment: You could use `projectile` or `find-file-in-project`. They have an `ido` completion back end. Unless it's really a zillion dirs. Hundreds or thousands of dirs should be fine.

Comment: @abo-abo: Thanks, this package does look interesting!

Comment: @abo-abo: Could you please post your comment as an answer, and I'll mark it accepted? The package is indeed doing exactly what I wanted! Hope it would be useful to someone coming across the same problem. Thanks!